# Text fields name error that coming from Viewmodel in form MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am using viewModel in text fields but the name of the model fields is not actual in browser viewsource. in browser viewsource it is showing model field name with viewmodel name like **name="ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword"** and also field id is showing like name so how i can fix this . i have added browser viewsource code and actual code Please review it. i hope you understand my question thanks.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public User UserDetails { get; set; }        
    public ResetPasswordModel ResetPasswordModel { get; set; }
}

public class ResetPasswordModel
{
  public string CurrentPassword{ get; set; }
  public string NewPassword { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ProductViewModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserDetails.UserID)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Current Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.CurrentPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "New Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Browser ViewSource**

you can see their it is not showing model fields names right

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ResetPasswordModel.CurrentPassword" placeholder="Current Password" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Current Password field is required." id="ResetPasswordModel_CurrentPassword"  type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ResetPasswordModel.CurrentPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword" 
placeholder="New Password" id="ResetPasswordModel_NewPassword" type="text"  data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Maxmimum 40 characters allowed" data-val-maxlength-max="40" data-val-minlength="Minimum 8 characters required for password" data-val-minlength-min="8" data-val-required="The Password field is required"  value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ActionName(ResetPasswordModel ResetPass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: If the field name is not "right" what do you expect it to be? Is the current name a problem and do you get errors? What exactly are the errors (if any)?

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue here, the name attribute for the input is: ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword, and this is correct. Please clarify, why this is a problem? and what is the desired behavior.

Comment: @Jasen field name should be NewPassword not ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword because it is adding ResetPasswordModel extra and as in my Model it it also NewPassword .

Comment: @HoomanBahreini but in my ResetPasswordModel it is only NewPassword please see above model. and i am not getting my input data from view to controller due to this problem.

Comment: Please show us your controller action.

Comment: @Jasen i have updated my code please review it.

Comment: The name of the property is not a problem in this case. But your controller and action names need to match `Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)` -- this looks for `ControllerController with Action()`.

Comment: @Jasen you are right!  as i know that it should be same that is not problem in my actual code both are same. so that is not problem only problem is that it is not showing Model field name right in view source as i said in my question.

Comment: @AsifShakir: Do you mean the name should be: NewPassword instead of ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set name property like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "New Password" , Name="NewPassword"})
```

Comment: This solution is more of a hack... the real problem is the mismatch of the Model between Controller and View... if you fix that, the MVC auto generated name is correct...

Comment: Probably he need UserDetails object in the view as well. So I don t think changing view' s model is the right solution.

Comment: @bthn yes you are right i have also need UserDetails in View as well.

Comment: Hmm changing view's model is not good solution but @HoomanBahreini is right. I think updating your Action's model to ProductViewModel is the right solution. Otherwise you have to set all name properties manually like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in your View your model is: `ProductViewModel`, but in your controller, you are expecting: `ResetPasswordModel`.

This is not right, either change the controller to accept: `ProductViewModel`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ActionName(ProductViewModel productViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

*In this case, this the input with name=ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword would be correctly bound to your model.*

Or change the Model in your view:

```
@model ResetPasswordModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserDetails.UserID)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Current Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "New Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

*In this case the input name would be: NewPassword*

Comment: solved my problem with this answer. @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResetPasswordModel.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "New Password" , Name="NewPassword"})

Comment: What you are doing is a hack... you should use the same Model in Controller and View... that's how MVC is designed to be used.

Comment: i also need UserDetails in my view also what should i do for UserDetails?

Comment: use `ProductViewModel` in both Controller and View. and don't change the auto generated name...

Comment: if i does not change the name i am not getting data from view to controller due to model field not matching with Text field name.so for name matching what should i do ?